# Reusing a HP laptop charger of 3 wires (logic inside)

Tags: battery-charging, charger, converter, ac-dc, laptop

I have an HP laptop charger 18.5v 3.5A (1X2057... WBGST0A...)

In the past the charger was working fine and I removed the tip for an experiment, so I can't check wires measuring the original tip.

Wires are White, Blue and black and without a load connected there is 0V between any combination of 2 wires.

What is each wire for? Is there a signal wire? If yes is based on a protocol or just a resistance? Do I need to put a resistance between 2 of the wires to satisfy the detection logic on the charger?

Is there any specification about the system used by HP chargers ?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/1434785/29943

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reuse an HP 45w charger for my Sony device by simply isolating the ID pin.

And also connecting my Sony plug two wires directly to the HP plug. I taped everything in place and voilà, it worked perfectly! I can also easily switch back to using the charger with my HP device if needed. The ID pin was easily isolated using a piece of wire insulation.

and this is how to use two wire PSU with HP device:

[image: https://highvoltageforum.net/index.php?PHPSESSID=ur7rb4ou0469ueec91455sopb1&action=dlattach;topic=827.0;attach=6083;image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the wires is for a communication link between the power brick and the device to make sure that they are compatible, i.e. that the brick can provide the correct voltage and current to the powered device.  While this does keep you from running into potential issues arising from using Any Old Power Supply with a plug that will fit, it also means that you have to buy Genuine HP (TM) bricks for your Genuine HP (TM) products.  If you want a hacking project,  you can try your hand at spoofing the protocol.

Comment: Spoofing the protocol is not an option for me, complex, time consuming and probably unnecessary if someone else has done previously. For the sake of hacking/reusing I can also break the plastic case and try to skip the detection system

Comment: @DanielPerez Sometimes the protocol is just to have specific resistances to simulate the laptop being present. The plug you cut off may have had a resistor in there too. If it was USB-C, then you likely need to communicate via Power Delivery protocol and chips for that exist.

Comment: The connector was not a USB C but a DC plug. And i would say that cables go to insider pin, outside of external cylinder and inside of external cylinder